# Enabling second UART in U-Boot

Tags: linux, embedded, u-boot, uart

I am working on a project with SAMA5D3-xplained board with CortexA5 processor and embedded Linux. I would like to send and receive some data via UART during U-Boot is running and before a kernel is loaded to the RAM. I have no idea what I should do. Should I add the second UART to U-Boot device tree source file?  Should I change something in a board configuration file? Do you have any ideas on what steps I should take to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**
I would like to use UART from U-Boot C code, not from U-Boot commands. I need to communicate with one of a peripheral device before the kernel is loaded to the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second serial, you can use `loady`, `loadb` or similar U-Boot commands (there are several serial protocols supported) to switch U-Boot into a mode when it expects data. Then you can use your serial terminal - for example *kermit* or *minicom* to send the file directly to the RAM.

Comment: I wasn't precise enough when I wrote the post. I would like to use UART from U-Boot C code, not from U-Boot commands. I've edited my question.